# element is nil and must be empty

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a legacy c++ application that communicates using XML, with the following xml schema for an element.

```
        <xs:simpleType name="CountryType">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="2"/>
                        <xs:maxLength value="3"/>
                        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="ABW"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="ALB"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="ALG"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="AND"/>
                        ...
                </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>

        <xs:element name="Country" nillable="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="CountryType">
                                        <xs:attribute ref="searchCriteria" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

Even though nillable is set to true, but when

```
<Country xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

is passed in, xerces-c schema validation fails, with the error message "element 'Country' is nil and must be empty".

Why does it fail?  CountryType has a minLength of 2, so I thought that should restricts it from being empty, but schema validation does not complain when the input is empty and the below is accepted.

```
<Country></Country>
```

Is there anyway to make it accept nil?

```
<Country xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

The xerces-c library used is of version 3.0. The schema parser settings are:

```
      XercesDOMParser *schemaParser = null;
      schemaParser = new XercesDOMParser();
      schemaParser->setDoNamespaces(true);
      schemaParser->setDoSchema(true);
      schemaParser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
      schemaParser->setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation(getSchemaFile());
      schemaParser->setIncludeIgnorableWhitespace(false);
      schemaParser->cacheGrammarFromParse(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML document is valid according to that schema. I have checked using an online XSD validator. So at first sight this looks like a xerces-c defect. However, two things make me cautious about that conclusion:

1. The use of xsi:nil with empty tags is standard usage. I would be quite surprised if such a defect survived until now in an XML processor as old as xerces-c.
2. You said that `<Country></Country>` is accepted. According to the XML specification there is no difference between `<Country/>` and `<Country></Country>`. ( see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags, rule [43] ). Again, xerces-c could have a defect in this area, but it would be a bit of a surprise (to me, anyway).

It's possible that you are using a very old version of xerces-c, with some unfixed defects - it might be worth updating to the latest release. If that doesn't fix it then I would contact the maintainers of xerces-c: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/feedback.html

Comment: xerces-c lib used is 3.0, and I added the schema parser settings used.  `<Country/>` works, `<Currency xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>` works also, but `<Currency xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>` fails.  It doesn't like the `xsi:nl="true"` attribute.  Since the element is marked as nillable, users using XML generation tools such as JAXB include that attribute, and it fails.

Comment: Simple type such as string with `xsi:nil="true"` would work, so I wonder if there is some special case with complexType elements.

Comment: It does sound like a xerces-c defect. If xsi:nil="true" is present then the tag must have empty content. I think xerces-c is getting confused about whether the tag is empty. I suggest that you contact their mailing list, supplying your xsd and XML.

Comment: will do.  Thanks.